# How can i change div position when web show in mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in `bootstrap` and `css` write this Bootstrap and CSS code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-4 col-md-12" style="background-color: yellow; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed;">
        <div id="nav">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.full-width-div {
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#nav {
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 96px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

but when i see my site on the mobile the nav div go to up of screen and now width set to `100%`,how can i design that? thanks.

Comment: You should checkout bootstrap once again. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: is it a nav bar, u trying to design?

Comment: Here is wrong classes assignment at all:
`<div class="col-md-1 col-md-4 col-md-12" style="background-color: yellow; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed;">` First read "Bootstrap getting started" and basics of bootstrap grid system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

col-md-1 col-md-4 col-md-7  please use total 12

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try , Bootstrap Navbar in Bootstrap way, In web, it will appear like:

[image]

In mobile, it will appear like :

[image]

Please Check out this code https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar